# pyethapp ImportError: cannot import name blocks

Tags: pyethereum, pyethapp

I installed `pyethapp` using `pip install -c constraints.txt pyethapp`.  The `constraints.txt` file has one line, `pyelliptic==1.5.7`, to prevent the install error mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/pull/198).  The install succeeded, but when I run `pyethapp` I get the following error:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/pyethapp/pyeth-venv/bin/pyethapp", line 7, in <module>
  from pyethapp.app import app
File "/home/ubuntu/pyethapp/pyeth-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyethapp/app.py", line 2, in <module>
  from ethereum import blocks
ImportError: cannot import name blocks
```

I went looking for the `blocks` module in `python2.7/site-packages/ethereum` and found the file `block.py`.  It appears as if the module was renamed, or that `pyethapp` was built for a different version of `pyethereum`.

The versions I'm installing (by default) are:

```
ethereum==2.0.4
pyethapp==1.5.0
```

Are these versions incompatible?  Can I fix the error by installing different versions? Is there another way to fix the error (with modifying the source code)?

Answer (score 4):

To get a working version in a virtualenv on Ubuntu 17 I first did (as per @audiomason suggestion above - I haven't tried without this step):

```
pip install ethereum==1.6.0 pyethapp==1.2.0
```

then (fixes [this](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/issues/199))

```
pip install pyelliptic==1.5.7
```

then (fixes [this](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/pull/254))

```
pip install tinyrpc[websocket]
```

It then works :-)

Answer (score 0):

This command will install a functional pyethapp:

`pip install ethereum==1.6.0 pyethapp==1.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, install an up-to-date pyethapp from github, according to the instructions at https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/wiki/Getting-Started#installing-from-github -- to summarize, something like:

```
~/ethereum$ git clone https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp
~/ethereum$ cd pyethapp
~/ethereum/pyethapp$ virtualenv .venv
~/ethereum/pyethapp$ source .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) ~/ethereum/pyethapp/$ # note the "(.venv)"
(.venv) ~/ethereum/pyethapp/$ pip install --editable .
```

But maybe use virtualenvwrapper's mkvirtualenv to make the virtual environment, and give it a better name, like this:

```
~/ethereum/pyethapp$ mkvirtualenv pyethapp
(pyethapp) ~/ethereum/pyethapp$
```